# Import "bpy" could not be resolved

Tags: scripting

I'm trying to edit and save a script in 'vs code' but somehow I'm getting the [Import "bpy" could not be resolved] error in the problems console below.

[image: screenshot]

I tried the solution posted here: [Linting Blender Python in VSCode](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/126322/linting-blender-python-in-vscode)

But adding that line to settings.json will not solve the issue. Any idea what I might be missing?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, installing the fake `bpy` module helped me.

https://pypi.org/project/fake-bpy-module-2.80/

Answer (score 0):

1. Uninstall Blender Dev
2. Uninstall Python
3. Reinstall Python
4. Reinstall Blender Dev